# Array_map() a simple cURL function

Tags: php

So I created a function with a cURL request inside and I get the data to print out when I do `print_r` which is great. I don't know how to array_map the data tho.

```
public function request()
{
    $resource = curl_init();
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_URL,
        'https://etc....'
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        ['API-Authorization: C:p']
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_REFERER,
        'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/'
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        'F'
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
        1
    );
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));

    return $response;
}
```

So I have that cURL request and would like to array_map() it but I can't seem to get it to work properly, I have tried doing this:

```
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
    $test[] = array_map('', $response);
    return $test;
```

With no luck, does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You are **decoding a string**, but need to **encode an array**. `$response = json_encode(['html' => curl_exec($resource)]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add true parameter to `json_decode` to get array instead of object.

https://www.php.net/json_decode

```
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($resource), true);
return $response;
```